# How can I use a variable or list item with xarray / rioxarray to identify a band for use in functions?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm attempting to iterate through netcdf files, and would like the band name that I'm working with to be defined by matching a list of expected bands with what is available in the netcdf. This part is working ok.

What I'm having trouble with is using subsequent functions where I would ordinarily call the band by name, and substituting in `listname[0]`.

For example:

Instead of using `bandcount = up_sampled.band_name.shape[0]` I would like to instead be able to use `bandcount = up_sampled.common_key[0].shape[0]` where `common_key` is the list.

The error is: ``'Dataset' object has no attribute 'common_key'```

I believe what I'm looking for is something similar to string substitution, but for substituting in the name of the band.

For the record, and anyone reading in future I'm matching the bands expected vs bands available in each iteration by using:

```
#Open the ds with rioxarray and call it ds_netcdf

#create list of keys w want to assess against
expected_keys = ['max_apples', 'max_oranges']

#print the variables in ds_netcdf
ds_keys = list(ds_netcdf.keys())

#find keys common to both lists, ds_keys and max_keys
common_key = list(set(ds_keys) & set(max_keys))
```

The trouble is when I try something like:

```
#determine the maximum number of bands in the raster
bandcount = up_sampled.common_key[0].shape[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to access like so:

`up_sampled[common_key[]].shape[0]`